# How to move all content (relative,absolute,...) down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have a unknown page with some content positioned relative, some absolute.
It has some scripts and there can be also lot of styles.

Is there any universal solution how to make on "every" **page content moved down by 50px** (for example), to make an empty space on top of page?

Using JS/CSS only. Validity has lower priority than functionality, you know..

Comment: Try a top margin of 50px on the `body` element....

Comment: and content will be placed next to `<body>` element?

Comment: (Moving the body down is bad practice leave the body as margin:0) You should enclose your page content with new div tags Id it and move it down via top:50px;.

Comment: Be careful about your `Validity has lower priority than functionality, you know..`, you're going to spur a debate, where everything is possible and able to get there with having valid code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a wrapper `div` and put a `margin`/`padding` on that.

You'll have to add positioning to the wrapper (`absolute`, `relative`, or `fixed`), anything but `static`, so that its children will position to it.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/VYYNj/)

---

Browsers behave differently when adding CSS to the `body` tag, which is why I don't recommend modifying that.

Comment: elements are absolute to their parent... if there are any absolute placed elements in the `body` they will now be absolute to the `body-wrapper` div

Comment: by adding a `margin-top:50px` to that body-wrapper, you will be shifting everything in the page down 50px.  Be aware that this applies to `absolute`,`relative`, AND `static` elements as well.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want to do this for the "alerts" that you see at the top of websites now (like stackoverflow). The way I normally do this is to add a `div` with id `message` as the first div after the body tag.

If you can't do this in the html, then just use JS to insert `div#message` as the first div in the DOM when the body tag opens. This way, whatever space the div takes, everything else will be moved down.

If you have absolute positioned elements, you **should** have all you pages content is a div wrapper which should have position set to relative. That way when the wrapper is shift down so will all the content be. Even if you can't modify the html, I'm sure there is such a wrapper in your html, just use CSS to change it's position property.

In jQuery you can just use [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to add a div as the first child of `body`.

```
$('body').prepend("<div id='message'></div>");
```

In pure javascript something like (untested):

```
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.setAttribute("id","message");
insertBefore(myDiv,document.body.firstChild);
```